# How to view all the overlapped images on map using swift?

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, swift2, instagram

I have placed a marker on my map which is in a form of image. Now when the photo is clicked in my application using the latitude and longitude, it gets displayed on map. My question is when more than two pictures are clicked on same place then they get overlapped on each other, how can I view both the images? Below is the image provided which I want as a final result.

[image]

Comment: You may check on this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30001/overlay-images-and-overlay-views-with-mapkit-tutorial). It discussed some points on how to overlay images. Also as stated in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier), clustering is not advisable to this if you have markers that could be in the exact same location, or close enough to overlap even at the maximum zoom level. In that case, clustering won’t help your users see and/or click on the marker they’re looking for.

Comment: thanks but this is not usefull